# Probability distribution of a Poisson process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, poisson-process

Given that $n$ events have occurred in a Poisson process $N(t)$ with rate $\lambda$ until the time $a$ . Find the probability distribution of $N(t)$ until the time $b$ where $0<b<a$

My attempt : $$P(N(a)=n)=\frac{e^{-\lambda a}(a\lambda)^n}{n!}$$
We have stationary increment. 
$$P(N(b)=k|N(a)=n) = \frac{P(N(b)=k,N(a)=n)}{P(N(a)=n)}$$
$$=\frac{P(N(a)-N(b)\leq n-k)}{P(N(a)=n)}$$

Is this correct and how to proceed further ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, but the last equality has some problem, here is the correct way to handle $P[N(b) = k, N(a) = n]$:
\begin{align}
& P[N(b) = k, N(a) = n] \\
= & P[N(b) = k, N(a) - N(b) = n - k] \\
= & P[N(b) = k] P[N(a) - N(b) = n - k] \quad \text{by increment independence} \\
= & P[N(b) = k] P[N(a -b) = n - k] \quad \text{by stationarity} \\
= & e^{-\lambda b}\frac{(\lambda b)^k}{k!} \times e^{-\lambda (a - b)}\frac{(\lambda (a - b))^{n - k}}{(n - k)!}
\end{align}
Simplification gives the final result (binomial distribution)...

Comment: Shouldn't be the desired distribution a function of $t$, with $t \in [0,b]$?

Comment: No, it is a function of $a$ and $b$. To clarify, the problem asks to find $P[N(b) = k \mid N(a) = n]$ for $k = 0, 1, \ldots, n$.